# PHP array and implode with blank/null values

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I have a array which i generated by values in a database, the example is below:

```
$addressarray = array($results['client']->client_city, $results['client']->client_county, $results['client']->client_postcode);
```

The values are entered by the user using a from, the above array works and the correct values are placed into it, however sometimes the user may not enter the clients county, so therefore

```
$results['client']->client_county
```

may be blank.
I call the array with this.

```
$address = implode("\n  ", $addressarray);
```

Now this is the part that i think need fixing, obviously if all the fields have a value then they are displayed with line breaks, but if like i mentioned above the county is blank it will stll output a line break so you will get:

```
city

postcode
```

but what i want is

```
city
postcode
```

I guessing the

```
\n
```

is the issue but am at a blank. any help appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to your array before use `implode()` function

```
$address = implode("\n", array_filter($addressarray));
```

Comment: wouldn't you need a call back for array_filter to check if the value is empty? or does array_filter do that by default?

Comment: @TheSnookier `If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.`

Answer (score 4):

try to use `array_filter()` on the `$adressesarray`, it filters empty values.
For more [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)