# PHP Display comma after each variable if variable is not empty

Tags: php

How to display comma after each variable only if that variable is not empty.

```
<?php echo $City; ?>, <?php echo $Province(); ?>, <?php echo $PostalCode(); ?>, <?php echo $Country(); ?>
```

Comment: `echo implode(', ', array($variable1, $variable2, ...));`

Comment: @billyonecan : [Won't work](https://eval.in/320220)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another way would be to put them inside an array in conjunction with `array_filter` to clean out empty strings and implode them:

```
$vars = array_filter(array($City, $Province, $PostalCode, $Country));
echo implode(',', $vars);
```

Sidenote: If you want to treat empty spaces also, you could map out `trim` on elements, then filter:

```
$test = array_filter(array_map('trim', array('1', ' ', 'test')));
                                              //   ^ single space
```

Comment: refer also to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860270/php-array-and-implode-with-blank-null-values