# PHP implode() remove comma

Tags: php, mysql

In this example I have two possibilities to display, which `car` is being `hired`, `where` and what `fuel type` it has. If the car is chosen for `different` `weekday`, it comes this:

> Ford, Philadelphia, Diesel
>
> Toyota, Philadelphia, Diesel
>
> Nissan, Philadelphia, Diesel, ,

If I choose One car for the whole week it comes only the one car:

> Ford, Philadelphia, Diesel

Here is the code, I am using to display them:

```
    } else {
    $carnames = array();
    foreach ($carname as $carraw) {
        $hirestation = array();
        if (!empty($carraw->name)) {
            $hirestation[] = $carraw->name;
        }
        if (!empty($carraw->cartype)) {
            $hirestation[] = $carraw->cartype;
        }
        if (!empty($carraw->address)) {
            $hirestation[] = $carraw->carfuel;
        }
        $carname = implode(', ', $hirestation);

        $dedupedroomnames[] = $roomname;
    }
    $carnames = implode('; ', $carnames);
    $strcar = (!empty($allcarnames)) ? $carnames : $carnull;
}
```

The `problem` is, that in case there were `multiple` `cars` for the week, at the end there are always this `two comas`:

> Ford, Philadelphia, Diesel, ,

After examing it, I found, that there comes the `car` for the `whole week`, if I choose it `together` with the `single choices`:

> Ford, Philadelphia, Diesel, ***Dodge, D.C, Gas***,

What I am missing within the code?

Comment: try using `array_filter` before imploding the array - it should remove empty values

Comment: Slightly confused by your foreach loop, you are looping through `$carname` but within the same loop you are then imploding hirestation onto the same variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that one or more values are blank or null.

Try to use `array_filter()` to filter out empty values.

You can find a similar issue here: [PHP array and implode with blank/null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860270/php-array-and-implode-with-blank-null-values).

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php